# AWS Device Farm and intranet integration through laptop

Tags: intranet, aws-device-farm

I have a mobile application developed in Xamarin that works in the proximity of a wifi (island network, no internet). I can connect the simulators on my MacBook via ethernet to the intranet. But is there a way to connect devices on AWS Device Farm to that and test on multiple devices?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Device Farm has a feature to support VPC endpoints. 
So essentially, if your endpoint can be put behind a [VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) or have an endpoint (proxy) on AWS that can talk to your endpoint then the device and the host machine on which your tests run will be able to talk to your desired endpoint.

Here is a reference about it:
[AWS Device Farm VPC feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/amazon-vpc-endpoints.html)